# Translating --「きめぜりふつかった」って？

Tags: grammar, words, conjunctions

Playing through a game, and I've encountered a verb / combination I've never seen before. The full dialogue is:

> もうお姫さまにきめぜりふつかったの？

Am I looking at some stem of きめ・る？ Or something else entirely? What's the statement mean?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the stem of 決める plus セリフ (plus the past tense of 使う): [決]{き}め[台詞]{ゼリフ} is one's "signature phrase".

The sentence is thus

> もうお姫さまにきめぜりふつかったの？
>   Did you already use your signature phrase on the princess?

I'll leave you to make sense of it in the context of your game.

Comment: You can look [here](http://cozalweb.com/ctv/kimezerifu/) what kind of セリフ are considered 決め台詞...